# Detect when VideoPlayer has finished playing

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I have a MovieController class that manages videos in my project. I'm using the new video player component introduced in Unity 5.6.

I would like to call a method when a movie has finished playing. So far, this method is only a `Debug.Log`, as you can see:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class MovieController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private VideoPlayer m_VideoPlayer;

    void Awake () 
    {
        m_VideoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        m_VideoPlayer.loopPointReached += OnMovieFinished; // loopPointReached is the event for the end of the video
    }

    void OnMovieFinished(VideoPlayer player)
    {
        Debug.Log("Event for movie end called");
        player.Stop();
    }
}
```

My issue is that the `OnMovieFinished` is not called at the end of the video, and I just end up with a black screen and nothing in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't trust or use the *events* from the `VideoPlayer` API because I've ran into problems with them too. What you see is a bug that hasn't been fixed for months.

If you want to detect if video has finished playing, use a coroutine to to check `videoPlayer.isPlaying` every frame in a while loop. When the while loop exists, it means that the video has finished playing.

```
while (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
{
    yield return null;
}

//Done Playing
```

I can't test this right now to check if the pause function affects `videoPlayer.isPlaying` but you can test that by yourself.

---

Another way to do this is to check if [`frame`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-frame.html) is the-same as [`frameCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-frameCount.html). When this is true, you know that the video has finished playing.

```
if(videoPlayer.frame == videoPlayer.frameCount)
{
    //Video has finshed playing!
}
```

If none of these solved your problem then file for a bug report.

Comment: `videoPlayer.isPlaying` wasn't working either, but the second method with `videoPlayer.frame` worked.

Comment: That's why I provided two ways to do it so that if one fails, another one would work. I think you should file for a bug report because your original code should actually work. It now seems to be working in my Unity 5.6 version.

Comment: framecount method worked well for me. But videoplayer does not reach framecount, so ended up comparing with framcount-1.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, this still doesn't work completely as expected in Unity 2018.4.25 (current version I'm working with). Playing videos on start-up will often result in isPlaying being false (jumping out of the video without playing it, whilst and testing for

```
(videoPlayer.frame == videoPlayer.frameCount)
```

doesn't seem to work reliably on mobile devices (android) as the video will stop playing (isPlaying == false) before the video has played all its frames (usually a couple short, which I assume is frame skipping).

I found

```
if (( videoPlayer.frame) > 0 && (videoPlayer.isPlaying == false))
```

captures the use case problems I was running into on mobile, however there may be more interesting use cases and combinations to deal with. I put the test above into an update() rather than a co-routine.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine.Video;

private VideoPlayer vid;
private float beginning;

void Awake()
{
    vid = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    beginning = Time.time;
    vid.Play();
    StartCoroutine(waitmethod());
}

IEnumerator waitmethod()
{
    while (Time.time - beginning < vid.length)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    runyournext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
videoPlayer.loopPointReached += OnMovieFinished;

//the action on finish
void OnMovieFinished(UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer vp)
{
    vp.playbackSpeed = vp.playbackSpeed / 10.0F;
}
```

you can see more here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html